# Why are all exceptions not build on the same model in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

While playing with loading and evaluating files (mainly for config loading), I came across several type of errors that can raise exceptions:

- the file doesn't exist raises `%Code.LoadError{file: ..., message: ...}`
- if there is some sort of syntax error in  the config file, one can get :

  - `%SyntaxError{description: ..., file: ..., line: ...}` or
  - `TokenMissingError{description: ..., file: ..., line: ...}`

Unfortunately those exceptions (`xxxError`s) are not built with the same parameters: error **description** has sometimes the key `description` and sometimes the key `message`. I find this quite annoying because one needs to check all possibilities which makes the code verbose and one can never be sure that for some other kind of error, an other key would not be used.

I was wondering if there was some reason for this and/or if this is considered as something to be corrected in the future releases by choosing one or another key (always tricky as a change will introduce backward incompatibilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these *do* have something common: they all implement the `Exception` behavior. The correct way to access the message for an `Exception` is to pass it to `Exception.message/1` (and not `exception.message`). An `Exception` may contain any fields (they're just structs) (check out `Kernel.Macros.defexception/1`), which is what you see when you print it using `IO.inspect`. They may or may not contain a `message` field, but they will always return a message when passed to `Exception.message/1`. Here's an example for all 3 errors that you mentioned:

```
defmodule Main do
  defmacro go(do: block) do
    quote do
      try do
        unquote(block)
      rescue
        e -> e
      end
    end
  end

  def main do
    e1 = go(do: Code.load_file("foo"))
    e2 = go(do: Code.string_to_quoted!("do: end"))
    e3 = go(do: Code.string_to_quoted!("do"))
    for e <- [e1, e2, e3] do
      IO.inspect {e.__struct__, Exception.message(e)}
    end
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
{Code.LoadError, "could not load /private/tmp/foo"}
{SyntaxError, "nofile:1: unexpected token: end"}
{TokenMissingError,
 "nofile:1: missing terminator: end (for \"do\" starting at line 1)"}
```